# Source files not located in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Where does Microsoft Visual Studio look for source files? I have this line of code in my program: 
IDB_EJECT_BTN           BITMAP                  "res/eject_butt.bmp"
that throws up an error saying line not found. I have included the res file containing the set of images in the output directory of the code program as well as the same director where the code program is located. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

"res" has to be a subdirectory of your project directory for this to work.  The project directory is the directory that contains your .vcproj file.